# Questions about rectangles, subcovering and cauchy sequnce in the proof of Heine-Borel theorem in the euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis, proof-explanation

This is from the book "multidimensional real analysis" by J.J. DUISTERMAAT and J.A.C. KOLK

[image]

The Proof:

[image]

[image]

I have a hard time understanding this, heres what i dont understand:

1)The first paragraph states that the collection of rectangles are obtained by subdividing each rectangle into $2^n$ rectangles by half.I dont know how to imagine or see "halving the edges of B" ,i need an intuition on that.

2)(The second paragraph)How do we know that there exist a rectangle such that O does not contain a finite subcovering of K∩$B_1$ that is nonempty,can we prove that?

3)(The third paragraph)Why is the sequence ($x_k$)=K∩$B_k$ is a cauchy sequnece(In particular, how to see that ($x_k$) is a cauchy sequnece with the reasoning that $B_k$⊂$B_l$ and the diameter formula(i also dont know how to get the formula))(needed more detailed proof)

Any help would be nice (if there are pictures to help understand it,that would be very much appreciated) , thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1)$:

In dimension $1$, this "halving" would look like the following operation: $$[-1,1]\to[-1,0]\cup[0,1]\to[-1,-1/2]\cup[-1/2,0]\cup[0,1/2]\cup[1/2,1]\to\cdots$$In general we call it "dyadic subdivision". It's a common way tool as its easy to describe and gives you good control over the size of the things you're dealing with. In dimension $2$, this would look like splitting a rectangle into four equal pieces, then into $16$, then into $64$, ...

[image]

(Subdividing into first dark blue then purple then light blue). You do the same in any dimension, and it *is* possible to formally describe this, it's just a pain.

$(2)$:

Consider that there are **finitely** (but at least one) many $B\in\mathcal{B}_1$ with $K\cap B\neq\emptyset$. If no such $B_1$ existed, then that means $\mathcal{O}$ admits a finite subcover of each $K\cap B$, and because there are finitely many of these, we could take the union of subcovers to find a finite subcover of $K$ by $\mathcal{O}$ - which is a contradiction. To get the idea, here's a basic example: suppose $\mathcal{O}$ is a cover of $[-1,1]=[-1,0]\cup[0,1]$ which has no finite subcover. If $\mathcal{O}$ admitted a finite subcover of $[-1,0]$, say by the sets $U_1,U_2,\cdots,U_n$, and if it admitted a finite subcover of $[0,1]$, say by the set $V_1,\cdots,V_m$, then we would find $\mathcal{O}$ has a finite cover of $[-1,1]$ - namely, by $U_1,U_2,\cdots,U_n,V_1,\cdots,V_m$.

$(3)$:

Well, I know that for any $n,m\in\Bbb N$, $x_n$ and $x_{n+m}$ are both in $B_n$. The diameter of $B_n$ is some constant ($C$) multiple of $2^{-n}$. That means, $\|x_n-x_{n+m}\|\le\operatorname{diam}(B_n)\le C2^{-n}$. To show the sequence is Cauchy, take any $\epsilon>0$. There is $N\in\Bbb N$ such that if $n\ge N$, we know $C2^{-N}<\epsilon$. So, $\|x_n-x_{n+m}\|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ and $m\in\Bbb N$... that means the sequence is Cauchy.

The sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is trapped in increasingly tiny boxes. As the diameter of these boxes decreases, the possible distance between $x_n$ and $x_{n+m}$ decreases too.